# Can I pass files between commands?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I am looking for a way to send the resulting file from one command to another, So I don't have to save a copy on disk in between. For example, if I have `rar`ed files on disk and want to open them I would like to be able to run something like:

```
unrar x file.rar | kplayer

unrar x file.rar | gpg -c

gpg file.gpg | kplayer
```

I am sure you see what I am looking for. I have tried to get `unrar` to send to standard output with `-p` but it will just send it to screen even when I think it should be connected with a `|` to kplayer. I suppose that is because kplayer can't get it's data from stdin.

But is there a way to pass files without saving them on disk? Is the best I can get to create a filesystem in memory and use that, I don't like the idea to reserve that much memory though.

Comment: Even if `kplayer` doesn't read from `stdin` by default (haven't used it, don't know it), you can still use a fifo file as an argument (see `mkfifo`) as a workaround. But it will still not work if the media format does not support streaming. What exactly are you trying to feed `kplayer`?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of commands have an option to write to `STDOUT`.  Unrar, for example, has the `p` option. A lot of commands then have the `-` option that can be used in cojunction to read from `STDIN`.  So the first example you gave could be rewritten like this:

```
unrar px file.rar | kplayer -
```

GPG already works with piped input by default:

```
unrar px file.rar | gpg -c
```

Check a command's help and/or man/info page if sending the results to `STDOUT` is supported (many commands do this by default).

Comment: You have to be careful when using - for stdin and might need to prefix it with -- to inform the command that it is a file argument and not an option.

Comment: Another option instead of using - is to use /dev/stdin as a file or /dev/fd/0 . Both are available on linux but I do not thing that it will make kplayer work because it likely needs a seekable file and not a stream/pipe.

Comment: @Richm Most programs recognize `-` as an operand, not an option. Both POSIX and GNU mandate that `-` be an operand.

Comment: Note that `p` and `x` are both commands and `unrar` accepts only one command. Using both as shown in the answer results a syntax error. As `unrar` writes its error messages to STDOUT instead of STDIN (probably a DOS legacy), it will be sent to `kplayer` instead of appearing in the terminal.

Comment: This is the key - a program has to support writing its output to stdout [or, in a pinch, to an arbitrary filename, for use with `>(process substitution)`], rather than creating a file. (in principle, the other program has to support picking up its input from either stdin or an arbitrary filename, but this is much more common)

Comment: @Gilles thanks - yes you are right. Was getting confused with file names beginning with a '-' where '--' marks the end of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If the command merely requires a file name, specify `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0`. These are special files; opening them actually duplicates standard input. Some commands accept `-` as an alias for standard input, too.

```
unrar p foo.rar somefile | somecommand -
unrar p foo.rar somefile | somecommand /dev/stdin
```

Occasionally a program imposes constraints on the file name, typically requiring a specific extension. You might be able to fool it with a symbolic link.

```
ln -s /dev/stdin myfile.ext
unrar p foo.rar somefile | somecommand myfile.ext
```

This won't always work, because some programs can't cope with piped input: they require seekable files, i.e., file where they can go back and forth at will. In that case, you need to make a temporary file.

In some cases, you can arrange for your data to appear as a regular file rather than as the output of a command. [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), in particular, can make all sorts of things appear as regular files. For example, with [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), archive members appear as files.

```
mountavfs
cd "~/.avfs$PWD/foo.rar\#"
somecommand somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a shell that supports [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), that might help with programs that can't take data from stdin.

You would do `kplayer <(unrar p file.rar)`

If you are quite desperate, you can use a [ramdisk](http://linuxfocus.org/English/November1999/article124.html), and actually create files, but they won't be on disk.

Comment: This is equivalent to using `/dev/stdin`: the data will still be coming from a pipe. The `<(…)` construct only becomes useful when you want to get input from several pipes (they can't all be stdin).

Comment: @Gilles It's not the same; data does not come from stdin. The `<(…)` is converted a filename, and that filename is passed to the program as an argument. So if the program does not read from standard in, but does take filename arguments, this is useful.

Comment: But the file name is `/dev/fd/NUMBER` or something like it, and the file is a pipe.

Comment: Exactly; it's a pipe, but not stdin, which is (I think) what the author was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

And thanks all for the input, i suppose there isn't any easy way to get what i want ;(

The following command should do and use the /dev/shm, So i need to build a nifty script :)

```
cp file.gpg /dev/shm && gpg -c file.gpg && rm file.gpg && kplayer file && rm file
```